# How to add a JWT to header after successful login

Tags: javascript, rest, api, symfony, authentication

I am building a web app using Symfony 4 and I am trying to implement the back end as a REST API.

As part of the login process, I have created an endpoint that returns a JWT upon receiving a valid username and password. I then save the JWT to local storage in the browser as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.js-login-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let username = $('#_username').val();
    let password = $('#_password').val();
    let data = JSON.stringify({_username: username, _password: password});

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/tokens',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
            // Add Header to the request Authorization: "Bearer " . data.token
            window.location='/app';
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            var errorData = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(errorData);
        }
    });
});
});
```

My question is how I can add the JWT to the header so I can redirect the user to the password protected area. My guard authenticator will then validate the token accordingly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean add JWT to the header in backend?
If yes, you can create middleware to check user is auth or not.
This is example :

```
// add jwt module
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

async function isAuthValid(req,res,next) {
  try {
    // check header
    let token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      // check token type
      token = token.slice(7, token.length).trimLeft();
    } else {
      return res.send('wrong token type');
    }

    if (token) {
      // ? check token
      let verifiedUser = await jwt.verify(token, 'somesecret', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err.message);
        } else {
          return decoded
        }
      });
      req.authUser = verifiedUser
      next();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send('no token provided');
  }
}

module.exports = isAuthValid
```

Registering as middleware on your route

```
const express = require('express');
const isAuthValid = require('./checkAuthUser.js');

const app = express();

app.get('/myRoute', isAuthValid, (req,res) => {
  return res.send('protected endpoint')
});
```

Comment: Looks like you have enough reputation for adding comments. If you have something to clarify, add a comment to the question. Get everything answered, then come here and give a thorough answer.